# What is the better way to get values from the links in JSON with Javascript

Tags: javascript

Im working with a microservice for matches in football games. Every MATCH has a HOME team and AWAY team.

```
matches" : [ {
  "start_at" : "2018-06-14T18:00:00.000+0000",
  "num" : 1,
  "knockout" : false,
  "scoreHome" : 0,
  "scoreAway" : 0,
  "scoreHomeET" : 0,
  "scoreAwayET" : 0,
  "scoreHomePenalties" : 0,
  "scoreAwayPenalties" : 0,
  "resultRegularTime" : 0,
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/matches/1"
    },
    "match" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/matches/1"
    },
    "away" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/matches/1/away"
    },
    "home" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/matches/1/home"
    },
    "round" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/matches/1/round"
    }
  }
},
```

In my react app, Im reading those values with axios. Everything is fine, but what is the better way to acess the JSON data of a link?

I want to get the value of the away team in the link:
     "away" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/matches/1/away"
        },

Something like 
    const awayTeam = {match.away} kind of stuff

What is the better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You mean the best way? Or any better way would be fine?

Comment: Sembei. What Im doing is: 

1- Get the value of the URL in the links tab. 

2 - Make another request to this URL and mapping to a variable in react. 

I want to know if theres a “lazy” way to do it. I think I’m being dumb doing it this way

Comment: You need server for what you are trying to achieve. Another way of doing what you want is using URLSearchParams.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could do it using `URLSearchParams`:

```js
var paramsString = "link=away&element=0";
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);

 var data= [{
  "start_at" : "2018-06-14T18:00:00.000+0000",
  "num" : 1,
  "knockout" : false,
  "scoreHome" : 0,
  "scoreAway" : 0,
  "scoreHomeET" : 0,
  "scoreAwayET" : 0,
  "scoreHomePenalties" : 0,
  "scoreAwayPenalties" : 0,
  "resultRegularTime" : 0,
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/matches/1"
    },
    "match" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/matches/1"
    },
    "away" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/matches/1/away"
    },
    "home" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/matches/1/home"
    },
    "round" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/matches/1/round"
    }
  }
}];

var numberofElement =  parseInt(searchParams.get("element"));
var kindofLink = searchParams.get("link");
console.log(data[[numberofElement]]._links[kindofLink].href);
```

Here is a link to [mozilla.org with example on how to use URLSearchParams similar to mine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).